# Change attributes of files in ZIP

Tags: windows, zip

I have one huge ZIP file, with 100s of directories and 1000s of files. These are also zipped ('nested' ZIP). What I want is to change the date/time attributes of all zipped ZIP files and 'core' files. Manually is not an option, would spend a day or 2 on it... I tried to find a program which can do this (BatchPurifier CAN do this (!), only for a certain set of file types so that doesn't help me). BulkFileChanger (tip from a friend) doesn't work, can't get into the ZIP.

Comment: What do you mean with 'core' files ?

Comment: Files that are not being a ZIP in a nested ZIP structure.

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the structure, use a [touch](https://www.google.com/search?q=touch+for+windows) utility to set all datetime stamps, zip again.

You may already have one on your disk, e.g. if it came with a development environment.

You can even do this [without external programs](https://superuser.com/a/764721/141909).

Comment: I had the same idea but I think  the problem here would be the zip files inside the zip files (recursive). One could unzip all sub-zip files as well but on rezipping it this would result in only one big zip file (one should not forget to removed the zip files). Other possibility would be to copy the zip file to a separate directory unzip, touch the files, rezip again, copy back the new zip file (note that here the recursive part has to be taken into account as well. new subdirectory etc.).

Comment: @albert I overlooked that - Recursively [unzipping is possible](https://superuser.com/questions/421915/how-can-i-recursively-extract-zip-files-on-windows-including-deletion) but whether recursively zipping is again possible will depend on what's in the ZIP files. And as the OP says, those are both ZIP files **and others**. So we need something that keeps track of all those internal structures, then 're-constructs' the outermost ZIP. Can be done with a lot of batch programming still, if e.g. the ZIP are extracted to folders named like e.g. *origfilename.zipdir'

Comment: This becomes a batch file programming question that way. @Wouter if you want to go that way you can post your question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)  as well. Make sure that you do not ask for a tool there (that would be off-topic).